# Clarification of functionality of Vector2.MoveTowards method

Tags: unity, c#

In Unity's [documentation for Vector2.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html), they assign a two variables, "speed" and "step".

"step" is simply speed * Time.deltaTime.

Why is this step variable assigned? What function does this serve that means the speed variable isn't used in place of step? What is this variable controlling when used in these parameters?

Comment: You could put `transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);` all in one line, but naming that last argument `step` makes the line a bit shorter, and clarifies intent. (Now I don't have to ask "why is speed being multiplied by delta time?" - the variable name clarifies "oh, that's the distance of one *step* in the movement")

Answer (score 1):

This variable is the maximum distance the object is allowed to move on this method-call.

You usually call MoveTowards in Update in order to move an object one step closer to its destination. But the frequency of Update calls depends on the current framerate. So on lower framerates you need to move the object further per update than on higher framerates. Which is what Time.deltaTime is for. It represents the time since the last update.